# MySQL Workbench created database is not showing in SQL Editor's Schema list?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Once I worked with MySQL Workbench. And i created database by EER Modeling section. Then I saw my created database in my created host's Schema lists. So I could connect to the host from my software.
But recently my newly created database is not showing in the host's Schema list. I tried to recreate host. But it's still unable to access to database from application.

I hope described my problem clearly, thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user used to access the schema actually has the permissions to do so. Use Workbench's admin section to grant appropriate permissons to the specific user.